# Is there a way this line of code would work header("Location: ../login.php");

Tags: php, html, authentication, redirect, header

Am trying to have `header("Location: ../login.php");` redirect me to `login.php`

I have tried the following:

- `http://localhost/willie/assets/php/login.php` - `header("Location: login.php");` 

  error 404
- `http://localhost/willie/assets/php/login.php` - `header("Location: ./login.php");`

  error 404
- `http://localhost/willie/assets/login.php` - `header("Location: ../login.php");`

   error 404
- `http://localhost/willie/assets/php/.../login.php` - `header("Location: .../login.php");`

  error 403

How can I remove the (assets) so that I can access the file `login.php`?

Comment: may you should using javascript

Comment: kindly elaborate

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, although you may need to update the path to the login page, as you didn't make it clear which path is the correct one.

```
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? "https://" : "http://";
header("Location: " . $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/willie/assets/php/login.php");
exit();
```

Make sure you call exit after the header.

I usually store the host, and then the path to the login page in constants, which makes it clearer.

```
header("Location: " . APP_URL . LOGIN_PAGE);
```

Comment: header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/willie/assets/php/login.php");
exit();

http://localhost/willie/assets/php/localhost/willie/assets/php/login.php  - Error 404

Comment: What's the actual path to the login page?

Comment: "/willie/assets/php/login.php"

Comment: I just realised what was happening, because there was no protocol set it was appending it to the currect url. I've updated my answer.